# Java Normal Import

Tags: java, import

What is the difference between the following two import Statements :-

1. `import  java.lang.Math.*;`
2. `import  java.lang.Math;`

As per my knowledge, normal import (not static import) imports all the classes of a package or a specific class but then what statement 1 (above) means.

Note: both statements compile.